# MS Word 2016 dropdowns under Windows 10 no longer function

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word 2016 dropdowns, such as

Table -> Convert text to table
Review -> Language -> Set proofing language

no longer function reliably under Windows 10.
Surprisingly, they sometimes do function (seldom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the issue occur with specific documents based on some particular templates? Create a new blank document and will the issue still occur?

You can try to repair your Office from Control Panel according to [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

If the issue persists, you can try to reset your Word by following the methods in the article: [How to reset user options and registry settings in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/reset-options-and-settings-in-word). There is an easy fix tool you can use.

You can also rename Global Template (%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm) to have a check.

Comment: The rename seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to see that my reply is helpful to your question. Please accept it as answer to help other users who encounter the same issue if your question was answered appropriately.